# Issue with Binance API fetch In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch-api, binance

My code works fine in [***anWriter***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ansm.anwriter) app but doesn't work in [***Chrome***](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) browser !

It freezes after reaching the ***Fetch*** line in ***Account_Fetch*** function !

If code ***works fine*** it will show ***OK*** message !

***Documentation*** :

[***Endpoint Security Type***](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#endpoint-security-type)

[***SIGNED Endpoint Security***](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#signed-trade-and-user_data-endpoint-security)

[***Timing Security***](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#timing-security)

[***Account Information***](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#account-information-user_data)

***Note*** : This account is for ***test*** and that's why I share my ***API Key*** and ***Secret Key*** !

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script>
let AccessKey="1q02kgTluaKFYH9vgBAQyIIIN7UmSSCZvI8dELzM4RsNR3WEWJJqb6cIdaPVkYjE";
let SecretKey="IFcsWGidd6WQFZMKlUMd9fzTn0ztBV8esRl1BSz5O9vrKClrlDXorVAxUxJGWkwk";
let ServerTime=0;
let MaxDelay=60000;

Process();

async function Process()
{
await Time_Fetch();
await Account_Fetch(AccessKey,SecretKey,ServerTime,MaxDelay);

alert("OK");
}

async function Time_Fetch()
{
let URL="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time";
let Request=URL;

let Fetch=await fetch(Request);
let JSON=await Fetch.json();
let Data=await JSON;

ServerTime=parseInt(Data.serverTime);
}

async function Account_Fetch(AccessKey,SecretKey,ServerTime,MaxDelay)
{
let URL="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account";
let Parameters="timestamp="+ServerTime+"&"+"recvWindow="+MaxDelay;
let Signature=CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(Parameters,SecretKey);
let Request=URL+"?"+Parameters+"&"+"signature="+Signature;

let Fetch=await fetch(Request,{method:"get",headers:{"X-MBX-APIKEY":AccessKey}});
let JSON=await Fetch.json();
let Data=await JSON;
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Im not sure what you expect the response to be. Try adding mode:"no-cors" in the fetch command.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following code - this one runs to the end. However i was toled that that "you can't make signed API requests from a browser"

```
async function Process()
{
await Time_Fetch();
await Account_Fetch(AccessKey,SecretKey,ServerTime,MaxDelay);

alert("OK");
}

async function Time_Fetch()
{
let URL="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/time";
let Request=URL;

let response=await fetch(Request)
.then(blob => blob.json)

ServerTime=parseInt(Blob.serverTime);
}

async function Account_Fetch(AccessKey,SecretKey,ServerTime,MaxDelay)
{
let URL="https://api.binance.com/api/v3/account";
let Parameters="timestamp="+ServerTime+"&"+"recvWindow="+MaxDelay;
let Signature=CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(Parameters,SecretKey);
let Request=URL+"?"+Parameters+"&"+"signature="+Signature;

let Fetch=await fetch(Request,{method:"get",headers:{"X-MBX-APIKEY":AccessKey}, mode: 'no-cors'})
.then(blob => blob.json)
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good except you're missing a `toString()` at the end of HmacSHA256 method.

```
let Signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(Parameters,SecretKey).toString();
```

this method return an object like this one (for example):

```
{words: [8], sigBytes: 32}
words: [8]
0: 670167524
1: 2092892393
2: 560578323
3: 567480325
4: -1211153183
5: -1038754858
6: 926457206
7: 683147716
sigBytes: 32
```

So, you need to convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

and need to change ServerTime to ServerTime.toString():

```
let Parameters="timestamp="+ServerTime.toString()+"&"+"recvWindow="+MaxDelay;
```